# Move payment for civievent to the confirmation page

Tags: civievent, payment-processor, omnipay

Is there a way to move the payment options to the confirmation page for events? I am using the onmnipay extension to work with paypal checkout. In order to move on to the confirmation screen, the user must pay first. This also makes it difficult for users to register more than one person at a time. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As of 5.63 there is a setting at Administer - CiviEvent - CiviEvent Component Settings to enable this.

Comment: Sounds like you found a bug! It may not be well tested with paypal.